# Store JS object array in a cookie, without plugins?

Tags: javascript, cookies

What's the best way to store this:

```
var mydata = [{'11 Alveston Road, Manchester':1},
              {'12 Plymouth Street, Liverpool':2}];
```

in a cookie to retrieve later?

I can obviously simply turn it all into a text string, and add some symbols as delimiters (hoping that those symbols don't occur anywhere in the data values), but it seems a bit hacky!

Also I'd like to avoid the jQuery cookie plugin etc if possible - I'm working in mobile, and each extra file call is a performance hit.

Thanks!

Comment: Use [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var myData = JSON.stringify(
    [
        {'11 Alveston Road, Manchester':1},
        {'12 Plymouth Street, Liverpool':2}
    ]
); // "[{"11 Alveston Road, Manchester":1},{"12 Plymouth Street, Liverpool":2}]"
```

The array is converted into a string in JSON format, which you can then use as the value of your cookie.  You can decode it with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

---

Note: since you are using mobile browsers, they're probably quite modern and so have JSON natively installed.  You can use [this library](http://www.json.org/) to work around this in these cases.